# Advanced Filter not working on second iteration of nested For Next loop vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, advanced-filter

I am writing a macro that will take a large data sheet and filter it onto another sheet, with the first criteria being based on a variable (Degree Level) determined by the iteration of the for next loop based on m, and the second criteria based on a variable (Major) determined by the iteration of the nested for next loop based on i.

The filter works on the first iteration of m but not on the second (there are only three iterations). Not sure what would cause the bug, but it is on the line below  'Populate filtered data sheet...' Below is my code. Thanks in advance!

```
Public SelColCode as string 
Sub FilterGrads()
Dim DegreeLevel as string

SelColCode = "H"

For m = 1 To 3
If m = 1 Then
    DegreeLevel = "B"
    Number_Of_Majors = Sheets("MajorList").Range("AC1").Value '16 in this case
ElseIf m = 2 Then
    DegreeLevel = "M"
    Number_Of_Majors = Sheets("MajorList").Range("AE1").Value '12 in this case
ElseIf m = 3 Then
    DegreeLevel = "D"
    Number_Of_Majors = Sheets("MajorList").Range("AE1").Value '8 in this case
End If

'Look through all the majors and fill in each row one at a time on the report
For i = 5 To 4 + Number_Of_Majors * 2 Step 2
'Select the Report Tab and select the major
    Sheets(SelColCode & " " & DegreeLevel & " Report").Select
    Major = Range("B" & i)

'Unhide the advance filter tab and then input the Degree level and major from above
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Advance Filter").Visible = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Advance Filter").Select
Range("A6:AA15").ClearContents
Range("E6").Value = DegreeLevel & ".*"
Range("F6").Value = Major

'Check if the "Filter Data" Tab exists and delete it then add a blank sheet with the same name.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter Data").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets.Add.Name = "Filter Data"
Sheets("Filter Data").Select
Sheets("Filter Data").Move After:=Sheets("Merged Data")

'Populate filtered data sheet using the advance filter function
Sheets("Merged Data").Range(Data_Range).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Advance Filter").Range("A5:AB6"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1"), Unique:=True

'Length of filtered data minus one to not include the variable titles is the number of graduates for that major
Grads = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

'do some stuff, then loop

Next 'i, major
Next 'm, degreelevel
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem but using `Option Explicit` would have picked up `DegreeLvel`.

Comment: Added Option Explicit and had the same results. The error I get is Run-Time '1004', Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: I just restructured my macro and rather than using a loop for m (degree level), I just copied everything three times and reassigning values for DegreeLevel. On the second degree level (what would be m=2), I am having the same error message so I do not believe the issue is in the For Next loop.

Comment: It's not helpful to post code which clearly does not compile. You are also missing an `End If`. Please post your actual code or a minimal replica of your code that exhibits your problem. Have you tried stepping through your code etc?

Comment: Edited (I removed the if statement evaluating m since it is not immediately to this question). I have stepped through, same error.

Comment: Check the values of variables as you step through. It's good practice to avoid Select.

Comment: When I step through, variable values are correct. What do you recommend I use in place of Select? @SJR

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure why this worked, but I made a filtered data tab for each degree level and then a separate If statement for each degree level option. The following is within each If level. Thanks for trying @everyonewhohelped

```
'Check if the "Filter Data" Tab exists and delete it then add a blank sheet with the same name.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter Data B").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets.Add.Name = "Filter Data B"
Sheets("Filter Data B").Range("A1").Select

'Populate filtered data sheet using the advance filter function
Sheets("Merged Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Advance Filter").Range("A5:AB7"), _
CopyToRange:=Range("A1"), _
Unique:=False

'Length of filtered data minus one to not include the variable titles is the number of graduates for that major
Grads = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1
```